# Where is a Photoshop created script stored?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am using Photoshop CS5 on the Mac. 
I created a script using the record button while I was doing various actions and I would like to edit that script.
I can't find where Photoshop put the script file on my disk.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop Scripts are programmed in a scripting langue like Applescript. You are your actually asking about a Photoshop Action you recorded using the Actions Palette? Unless you saved the action set you recorded the action in.  The only place that action is stored in is in your Photoshop Preferences folder in the file "Actions Palette".   The Actions Palette is a full fledged Action editor. You can edit the actions loaded in the action palette.  You should also remember to save the actions sete you edit actions in or record new actions into. If you do not save then you will loose them if you reset your Photoshop preferences.

Comment: Sorry i was using a French version where they used "Script" in the menu for "Action". So yes it definitely is an Action that I recorded. But I don't understand what you call the "Preferences folder". Do you mean Preferences menu ? Or is it a folder on my hard drive ? Either way I couldn't find an "Actions Palette" file. Please advise. Thanks.